# Where's the GUI for the Gnuboy-x Gameboy emulator?

Tags: 16.04, games, gui, emulation

I just installed the Gnuboy-x binaries and I'm not sure how to use Gnuboy... Am I missing downloads or do I just need a GUI, and which GUI should I be using if it doesn't come with one?

Comment: To 'Close' voters: I have edited the question title for improved clarity and also edited the question body for the same purpose. Also added a quite reasonable answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package does *not* have a graphical user interface (GUI) and needs to be used purely from a Terminal. Confusingly enough the command to run Gnuboy-x is actually `xgnuboy` and the options are as follows:

```
andrew@athens:~$ xgnuboy --help

gnuboy 1.0.3
Usage: xgnuboy [options] romfile

      --source FILE             read rc commands from FILE
      --bind KEY COMMAND        bind KEY to perform COMMAND
      --VAR=VALUE               set rc variable VAR to VALUE
      --VAR                     set VAR to 1 (turn on boolean options)
      --no-VAR                  set VAR to 0 (turn off boolean options)
      --showvars                list all available rc variables
      --help                    display this help and exit
      --version                 output version information and exit
      --copying                 show copying permissions
andrew@athens:~$
```

However this application worked poorly on my own system, better in my opinion to use `vbaexpress` which has the nice gui you are after and which can be simply installed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install vbaexpress
```

This had me playing GameBoy roms in no time:

[image]

The particular rom I tested can be found [here...](http://download.freeroms.com/gameboy_advance_roms/game_and_watch_gallery_4.zip)

Comment: I only get a white popup (that claims to be running at 100%). I'm using a Pokemon FireRed rom, if that helps.

Comment: @James I am afraid that I get the same screen with that rom :(. Looks like some work and some don't...

Comment: Alright. Pokemon Red works just fine, but FireRed is my favorite.  Is there a list of working roms somewhere? Also, why is my emulator running at 105%? Is there a way to lower it to just 100%?

Comment: Did some research and found out everyone has this problem with Gnuboy. There is supposedly a patch that fixes it, but I have to put a file in the same folder as the emulator, so I assume that is referring to Windows... Where should I put this to get it to work?

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant VBA, not Gnuboy.

Comment: @James It would be interesting to see the patch, but also interesting is the newer version of gnuboy available from sourceforge: 1.0.5 which might be worth looking at. Looks like downloading roms is fraught with a few legal issues so I might stay away from that one :)